# Weird material issue in shading view

Tags: materials

I downloaded this 3D model from Sketchfab and it seems to be having some weird issue with the material.
The hands and body act kind of transparent but not the head or the shoes. (I don't really know how to word this issue so sorry if it's unclear)
[image]

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file or at least a part of it (upload and copy paste he URL it will generate): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/c24a47d97a284dad9359ecd6520c1cb8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *Material* panel, under *Settings*, disable *Show Backface*:

[image]

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!